# ERC20 Contract created but how to access those funds?

Tags: contract-development, erc-20

I have created a ERC20 token, and whilst creating a token Wallet my system got hanged, I can see the contract in Custom Token but its greyed out also I can see the token on etherscan.io/token.
Is there any way I can send and receive money through this newly created token?

Comment: You will need to provide more information like which contract code you used - ERC20 is just an interface and no implementation

Comment: I used ethereum ERC20 coin from https://www.ethereum.org/token

Answer (score 0):

When using the token-contract from https://www.ethereum.org/token as you mentioned in the comments, then the deploying account owns the total supply after deployment. So with this account you can transfer() the tokens.

Comment: Thanks, it means that when somebody sends ethers to this contract it will come to the deploying contract?

Comment: Also in Custom Tokens section why this newly deployed contract is greyed out?